# Aggregate $substr in Mongodb C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, group-by, substring

I starting using a MongoDB in my application. I im using Robo 3T to learn and test the queries and now, I'm translating the queries to C#.

**MY QUERY ON MONGO ROBO 3T**

```
db.dbCENTRAL.aggregate([
          { 
              $match: { PartnerId: "2021", DATAINST: {$gte: "2018-01-01 00:00:00", $lte: "2019-03-12 23:59:59"}, }   
          },

          { 
               $group: { _id:  { $substr : ["$DATAINST", 0, 10 ] }, count: { $sum: 1 }}
          }
])
```

Running the script above on Robo 3T its retrieved this result:

```
{
    "_id" : "2018-01-10",
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "2018-02-09",
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "2018-02-26",
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "2018-03-02",
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "2018-03-08",
    "count" : 1.0
}
```

Now, im trying to reproduce this result on my .NET MVC project and I'm facing difficult to translate the substring to C#.

**C# CODE**

```
var connString = "mongodb+srv:";
var client = new MongoClient(connString);
var db = client.GetDatabase("SyncMaster");
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("dbCENTRAL");

var match1 = new BsonDocument("$match", new BsonDocument("PartnerId", "2021"));

var match2 = new BsonDocument { { "$match", new BsonDocument { { "DATAINST", new BsonDocument { { "$gte", data1 }, { "$lt", data2 } } } } } };

var group = new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "$group",
                        new BsonDocument
                            {
                                { "_id", new BsonDocument
                                             {
                                                 {
                                                     "Dia", "$DATAINST"
                                                 }
                                             }
                                },
                                {
                                    "Count", new BsonDocument
                                                 {
                                                     {
                                                         "$sum", 1
                                                     }
                                                 }
                                }
                            }
                  }
                };

var pipeline = new[] { match1, match2, group };

var result = collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline).ToList();
```

That way is working fine, but, it's grouping by entire string Date, and I would like to group by short string date like: "2019-03-01".

I tried this way, but not worked, it returned _id: null

```
{
   "Dia", "$substr : [$DATAINST, 0, 10 ]"
}
```

Then I tried this:

```
 {
   "Dia", new BsonDocument {

                               {
                                   "$substr",  "[$DATAINST, 0, 10 ]"

                                }
                            }
  }
```

I got this error:
**MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: 'Command aggregate failed: Expression $substrBytes takes exactly 3 arguments. 1 were passed in..'**

I also tryed:

```
{
   "$substr",  "[\"$DATAINST\", 0, 10 ]"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just using the fluent C# syntax for creating aggregation pipelines?

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Central>("dbCENTRAL");

var filter = Builders<Central>.Filter.Eq(x => x.PartnerId, "2021")
                       & Builders<Central>.Filter.Gte(x => x.DATAINST, "2018-01-01 00:00:00")
                       & Builders<Central>.Filter.Lte(x => x.DATAINST, "2019-03-12 23:59:59");

var listAsync = await collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(filter)
    .Group(central => central.DATAINST.Substring(0, 10), g => new { Id = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Hi @Kelvin Smith thank you very much for your reply. No, I have not tried fluent C# syntax, I thought that way I was trying was more performatic. Your suggest worked perfectly thank you again!

Comment: @RogerioAzevedo the fluent way just means that everything will have type checking at complie time, the aggregation that is built should be identical.